# What is the meaning of an oxide being 'Higher' or 'Lower'?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

To put it simply, many books use the term 'Higher Oxide' or 'Lower Oxide'.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it generally means that the average oxidation state of the metallic element in the oxide is higher or lower. You can also say that the mass percentage of oxygen in the oxide is higher or lower.